# Change color output at console print in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a command line tool with Swift and I'm having trouble displaying colors in my shell. I'm using the following code:

I trying a lot solution but always the same thing

```
print("\u{001B}[0;33myellow")
```

OUTPUT:[0;33myellow

I expect the output is change color in console, is like to logcat

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't support console coloring since Xcode 8

but you can use **emojis** instead! for example you can use You can use `⚠️` for warning messages and  for error messages. (like the Xcode itself)

Or simply use these note books as a color:

```
: error message
: warning message
: ok status message
: action message
: canceled status message
: Or anything you like and want to recognize immediately by color
```